# addEventListener to the whole body of a page except one div

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there was any way to add an event listener to the whole page except one div in it. To be more specific in the example below is there any way to add an event listener to the body except the div?
e.g

html:

```
<body>
 <div class="sssss"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The event listener is always only attached to the element you call `addEventListener` on. Please try to give more detail as of what you need to do.

Comment: Check if the `event.target` has the class `sssss`. If yes, then just do nothing.

Comment: @Andreas Given the current level of information provided, that is just a guess. OP needs to clarify their needs. Not processing the event is one approach; another one could be to prevent the propagation of the relevant event on `div.sssss`.

Comment: You can create bunch of `if` in event's callback function to perform action on specific elements.

i believe, there is no direct way to eliminate child elements from attaching event.
(correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: **Again, your question lacks essential information to be answered. Please fix that.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the `target`s class name.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('sssss')) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Given the current level of information provided, that is just a guess. OP needs to clarify their needs. Not processing the event is one approach; another one could be to prevent the propagation of the relevant event on `div.sssss`. On top of that, the classList is certain to **never** contain `.sssss`, because that is an illegal class identifier. Either do `e.target.matches('.sssss')` or `e.target.classList.contains('sssss')`.

Comment: @connexo I agree with you, but I leave my answer to show the OP a possible way to achieve his needs.

Comment: At least fix your error. Your current answer is just **wrong**.

Comment: A dot to much... I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using JQuery : 
html :

```
<body id='myBody'>
    <div id='noActionDiv'></div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
$("#myBody").click(function(e){
    var myID = e.target.id;
    if(myID!='noActionDiv'){
        //your action here
    }
});
```

Comment: OP has not asked for a jQuery solution, which btw does not add anything helpful here. In fact jQuery does have a convenience advantage over the native DOM API with regard to delegate listeners (`$(selector).on('click', ':not(.sssss)', function... )`, which *your* jQuery answer fails to even mention.

Answer (score 0):

addEventlistener has to be called for each element individually.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Here is an example of how to attach an event listener to all elements within the body element excluding the ones with the class "sssss":

```
// define callback function once to avoid memory issues
function processEvent(e){
  /* do something */
}
// get all elements except those with class sssss
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *:not(.sssss)');
for(i=0 ; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', processEvent, false);
}
```

Comment: I thought this way too, but connexo will be unsatisfied with that also.

Comment: @kmgt No, this honestly is the answer to the (bad) question as it currently stands. In practice, you certainly wouldn't be doing that, but rather work with a delegate listener (like you suggested), but information OP gave is too thin to decide.